# TestNg with groovy, error ShortTypeHandling in Java

Tags: java, string, groovy, testng, noclassdeffounderror

I have a problem when i need to write something to String:

```
public static String loadAuctionId(String app, String auctionNumber, @Optional(".mu") ??final String userPostfix){
            String auctionId=auctionNumber;
            if(auctionNumber.equals("prop")){
                TestHelper2 testHelper = new TestHelper2();
                Properties prop=testHelper.loadProperties();
                auctionId=prop.getProperty(app+".auction.id.latest"+userPostfix);
            }else{
                auctionId=auctionNumber;
            }
            return auctionId;
        }}
```

in this line - `auctionId=prop.getProperty(app+".auction.id.latest"+userPostfix);` I have an error:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/codehaus/groovy/runtime/typehandling/ShortTypeHandling
```

How can i resolve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ShortTypeHandling class was introduced in groovy-all-2.3.x.jar. Try replacing your existing groovy-all-x.x.x.jar with groovy-all.2.3.x.jar

Answer (score 1):

I've solved this issue by adding this dependency on my POM:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
  <artifactId>groovy-backports-compat23</artifactId>
  <version>2.3.5</version>
</dependency>
```